# Bounds of std::string::find_first_of

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a string `foo` and I want to search for the second period, if any.

I'm using this code:

```
 std::size_t start = foo.find_first_of('.');
 if (start != std::string::npos){
     std::size_t next = foo.find_first_of('.', start + 1);
     /*and so on*/
```

I'm wondering if this is well-defined if the first period is at the end of the string.

I think it is since `start + 1` will be on the null-terminator, so I'm not in any danger of accessing any memory I shouldn't.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first dot is at the end of the string, it's at index `size() - 1`.

So then `start + 1 == size()`, meaning that [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) will look in the interval `[size(), size())`. This is an empty interval, so no memory accesses will be made at all.

Answer (score 0):

There may well not be a null-terminator at that point. (The standard does not guarantee it: `c_str()` is required to add one if necessary).

But your code is fine in any case. The behaviour on setting a pointer to point to 1-past-an-array is well-defined, so it's permissible to call the function with `start + 1` is `start` is the last character in your string. Internally, a *dereference* of that pointer will not take place you're outside the region that `find_first_of` will search.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard does not impose any restriction on the value of the second parameter.

The function tries to calculate an actual position `xpos` the following way

```
pos <= xpos and xpos < size()
```

If it is unable to find such a velue it returns `std::string::npos`

For example

```
std::string s( "AB" );

auto pos = s.find_first_of( "A", std::string::npos );
if ( pos == std::string::npos ) std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
```

The output is

```
Not found
```